# unlink(/home/goode/public_html/private/uploads/405/): Is a directory, though file_exist is checked

Tags: php, file-upload

In my form, I have more then 10 file uploads fields,

I have checked file exist though it is giving me error as below

my code is below,

```
 if (file_exists($filename))
                unlink($filename);
```

still it gives me error like below,

```
unlink(/home/goode/public_html/private/uploads/405/): Is a directory
```

Comment: The `file_exists` function checks whether the given path is a file or directory. So it makes sense that it passes that check. You can read more on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: @hetal gohel, you are absolutely wrong. `file_exists` function can be used to determine whether the exact file exists in a given directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
if (is_file($filename)){
    unlink($filename);
}
```

The `is_file` function checks if it's a file. `file_exists` checks if it's a file OR directory. A bit confusing I will admit.

Comment: Thank you very much, let me check above suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if

```
$filename = image.jpg
```

to proceed with your approach you should use,

```
if (file_exists(/home/goode/public_html/private/uploads/405/$filename)){
unlink(/home/goode/public_html/private/uploads/405/$filename);
}
```

if

```
$filename = /home/goode/public_html/private/uploads/405/image.jpg
```

you should use,

```
 if (file_exists($filename)){
    unlink($filename);
 }
```

Intelligent people always understand the others mean. It's not any big deal.

Of course, `file_exists` function can be used to determine whether the exact file exists in a given directory.

I created a demonstration page for those who have misconception about `file_exists` function.

I hope it helps others who are eager to learn the facts. A single task can be done in many ways in PHP.

***[Demo about how PHP copy, file_exists and unlink functions work?](http://klantoaguntuk.orgfree.com/demo-of-php-copy-file-exists-unlink-functions.php)***